# Setup Linksys 3200 remote access

Tags: networking, router

I'm trying to setup remote access for my linksys 3200 so that I can configure it through the WAN port. I have turned on remote access, however when I try to connect I get a 404 error. The settings I have are:
[image]

When I try to access xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9999 I just get a 404 error. I have allowed RDP access to a computer behind the router and this works fine on the same IP address. Any idea's on what else I have to do to allow remote management access?

---

UPDATE:
I tried changing the port to 80 and it works. Change it back to any other number and it doesn't work. Modem is setup with a DMZ to the router's IP. Why does it only work on port 80? BTW I can't use port 80 because there is a website hosted behind the router.

Comment: A 404 error means the URL is incorrect. Are you sure you're using the outside IP address assigned to that very device?

Comment: I'm sure it's the right IP (I can use the same IP over the internet to access RDP). It may not be a 404 error. If I access the IP from my phone I get "Webpage not available" and from my work computer: "Error Code 10060: Connection timeout 
Background: The gateway could not receive a timely response from the website you are trying to access."

Comment: Are you putting a `:9999` on the end of the URL?

Comment: yes. As per the question, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9999. I've also tried other ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that my work place and my phone both block a huge number of outbound ports. I tried on my friends computer and it works great on any port I chose. Try the same thing on my phone or work computer and I get a message saying it can't connect. Spoke with the network guys here at work and they confirmed that they do block most out-bound ports.